# Wordpress theme: where can I fix cart and checkout design?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a basic wordpress [website](http://www.legionarypc.com/) with the woocommerce plugin and tesseract theme, and I want to know **where I can fix the design** related to following issues:

1. On the cart page the dollar sign for the totals for a product are on a different line than the number. The same thing happens on the checkout page.
2. Some boxes are gray and some are white which looks nice, but on the checkout page, some of the boxes that should be grey are white, making it look bad. Can anyone tell me where in the code I can fix this?

The two pages in question are the cart and checkout pages. I would post code, but the problem is that I don't know where to find the specific section from where to fix the issue.

Comment: You need to check CSS / HTML of your website ? for more details please provide more informations about your website's framework / software

Comment: Sorry! It's just a basic wordpress website with the woocommerce plugin and tesseract theme, the two pages in question are the cart and checkout pages. I would post code, but the problem is that I don't know where to find the specific section from where to fix the issue.

Comment: Please help me out guys, its gotta be the easiest fix I just don't know where to look

Comment: http://imgur.com/IAJROKD this is a picture of the issue